# ViewPager Fragments are not initialized immediately

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager

I have a `ViewPager` with an adapter of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. For the sake of simplicity I have 2 Fragments within my ViewPager.

```
class MyPagerAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fragmentManager) {
    var firstFragment: SampleFragment? = null
    var secondFragment: SampleFragment? = null

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when(position) {
            0 -> SampleFragment()
                .also { firstFragment = it }
            1 -> SampleFragment()
                .also { secondFragment = it }
            else -> Fragment()
        }
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 2
    }

}
```

My `SampleFragment` is a simple Fragment with a `TextView` on it's view.

```
class SampleFragment: Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sample, container, false)
    }

    fun setText(text: String) {
        text_view.text = text
    }
}
```

Now I am on my MainActivity where I have ViewPager, I have below lines

```
val adapter = MyPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager)
view_pager.adapter = adapter

adapter.firstFragment?.setText("Some Text")
```

So, here is a problem. After initializing (setting adapter) my ViewPager I expect my fragments are created. But it is not the case. My fragments are initialized after a certain delay. So when I want to set text of TextView inside my fragment with the line

```
adapter.firstFragment?.setText("Some Text")
```

`firstFragment` is null.

When I debug, I see that after

```
view_pager.adapter = adapter
```

`getCount()` of adapter is getting called. And then 
adapter.firstFragment?.setText("Some Text")
will be executed which doesn't have any effect as `firstFragment` is `null`. And after a second or so `getItem()` of adapter is getting called.

So my question is why is my viewpager adapter fragments aren't getting initialized immediately. If I am missing something could you point out. Or it is expected behavior of ViewPager Adapter then how can I make viewpager fragments get initialized whenever pager is initialized?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that while creating your adapter, you are running `onCreate` from your `Activity`.
Fragments views initializations are done only after Activity has finished his own view initialization. So, fragments views are not accessible in `onCreate`.

So, to initialize some fragment values you can do this:
(code in java, you can change to Kotlin...)

```
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                   // init for first fragment
                break;   
                case 1:
                   // init for second fragment
                break; 
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Your suggested way works, but think about of server call which works asynchronously so you assume that your fragments are initialized when you get the result. Since you would not want to do your server calls inside `onPageSelected` of viewpager, but on `onCreate`, I was kind of looking for way to do on `OnCreate` method. Or in other words in a blocking fashion.

Comment: What about saving your server call results in local variables and then using these variables in onPageSelected?

Comment: that even complicates this approach. Think about server comes after onPageSelected is called. That means you have to have setting featuring for both onServerResult and onPageSelected

Comment: You mentioned about after onCreate of activity. So is there anywhere else that I can assure that onCreate is finished?

Comment: Another approach could be to initialize your `viewpager` only after `onServerResult`. 
So, in `onCreate` you can call your server values, in `onServerResult`, you can setup your viewpager, and in `onPageSelected` (`onPageScrolled` for first time) you can update fragment views.